# Firebase Admin SDK throws NoSuchMethodError while executing .jar file

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-admin

When I execute my app with basic Firebase setup as shown below

```
FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
  .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount))
  .setDatabaseUrl("https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com/")
  .build();

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance() // error
```

I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.checkNotDeleted(FirebaseApp.java:314)
```

I saw that this might happen because of the low guava version, but the thing is, I'm not using it as a direct dependency (only through Firebase).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in my code, not Firebase SDK. I was trying to load config json file from my resources folder and when I moved it to the project root directory as shown in this [demo](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-java/tree/master/database), it started working.

Comment: Hey, I'm experiencing the same problem. Do you know why moving json file worked for you?